# Install / Uninstall php-5.2.17 using phpfarm

Tags: php, server, phpfarm

I installed php-5.2.17 earlier using simply

```
./compile.sh 5.2.17
```

I didn't define any custom options. But later I realized that it is using cgi and I want it to use fastcgi so i created the custom file as

```
configoptions="
    –enable-cli \
    –with-pear \
    –with-openssl=/usr \
    –with-iconv \
    –with-curl \
    –with-mysqli \
    –enable-mbstring \
    –enable-exif \
    –with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
    –with-zlib \
    –with-zlib-dir \
    –with-png-dir=/usr \
    –with-gd \
    –with-gettext \
    –enable-gd-native-ttf \
    –with-mhash \
    –enable-ftp \
    –with-pspell \
    –with-mcrypt \
    –enable-bcmath \
    –with-mime-magic \
    –with-pdo-mysql \
    –enable-sockets \
    –enable-soap \
   –enable-calendar \
    –enable-fastcgi \
    –enable-force-cgi-redirect \
"
```

Now when i compile using the above command, it gives

```
5.2.17 5 2 17
configure: error: can only configure for one host and one target at a time
configure.sh failed.
```

Please note that I have patched all the necessary stuff that needs to be as per online tutorials.

I am using Ubuntu 14.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read through the php-farm github page and [this](https://github.com/fpoirotte/phpfarm#bonus-features) part caught my attention.

It describes that a `custom/default-versions.txt` file is often used to recompile the same php version.

Comment: But no such directory or file exists in my case

Comment: Are you inside the `php-farm/src` directory?

Comment: o yes... tried to find it is src directory.. and i think it is something we need to create for default configuration